# Why isn't this Vim key map to navigate buffers not working?

Tags: vim

I've added these to my `.vimrc`

```
nmap <silent> <C-right> :bn<CR>                                                                                                                                                        
nmap <silent> <C-left> :bp<CR>
```

They're not working! I tried substituting `C` with `S` and `M` but still no dice.

I'm on OS X terminal with "Use Option as Meta key" turned on. Most similar mappings work. I think it may be the combination with the arrow keys?

Answer (score 0):

On OS X, `Ctrl-<Right,Left>` are consumed at the OS level by Mission Control (they are switch to prev/next workspace). You'll need to disable those before they will be sent through to Vim.

- System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts
- Mission Control section
- Un-check "Move left a space" and "Move right a space"

Comment: Thanks. They are unchecked. I don't use that functionality. I don't think I have anything else bound to that. Also, I tried `S` and `M`

Comment: I unchecked those key maps in OS X on my system and it turns out they don't seem to be sent to Vim via iTerm. I'm not sure why, though...